# C++ atomic CAS(compare-and-swap) operation does not change value

Tags: c++, atomic, compare-and-swap

In the following example, what actually happens? Why value does not changes after successful exchange?

Live: https://wandbox.org/permlink/f5VYSKfQ9UJqa8FQ

```
std::atomic<bool> flag{false};

int main()
{
    std::thread thread([](){
        while(true){        
            // wait until flag not becomes true
            {
              bool expect = true;
              while(!flag.compare_exchange_strong(expect, false, std::memory_order_acq_rel)){
                  std::cout << "wait" << std::endl;
              }
            }
            
            std::cout << "work" << std::endl;
        }
    });
    flag.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    thread.join();
}
```

Output:

```
work
wait
work
wait
...
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What output would you expect to see?

Comment: I don't think you understand what `compare_exchange_strong` does. It is a convoluted operation. Read the reference about it https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange

Comment: @jtbandes I would expect "wait wait work wait wait..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens with:

```
          bool expect = true;
          while(!flag.compare_exchange_strong(expect, false, std::memory_order_acq_rel)){
              std::cout << "wait" << std::endl;
          }
```

when the flag is false.  The first time the test in the while loop runs, `expect` will be true, so does not match the flag.  So `expect` is updated to the false, and the function returns false.  So `wait` is printed and the loop repeats.
The second test in the loop, `expect` will now be false, which matches `flag`, so `flag` will be set to false (a noop as it already is), and the loop will exit.

The net effect will be to always set `flag` to false, and print `wait` if it was already `false`.  Thus, the output you see.

Comment: Yes - you're right. That's all because `expect` is updated in loop. Changing await loop do the trick https://wandbox.org/permlink/AU8wXOSCCGV3q78r